# Time Complexity

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursion, recursive-algorithms, analysis-of-algorithms

Prepping for an exam and wondering whether I correctly calculated the time complexity. Function is given as:

$function XYZ(n:integer)\\
        begin
           for\ i:=1 \ do \ 2*n^2 \ do;\\
           if \ n = 1\ then\ return (2);\\
               else \ return(2*XYZ(\lfloor(XYZ(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)/2\rfloor) - XYZ(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + XYZ(\lfloor n/2) \rfloor)); $

From that since we have five recursive calls:
$$T(n) = 5*T(n/2) + 2n^2$$

Since:$$a = 5 \ b=2 \ d(n) = 2*n^2$$
$$a < d(b) => n^{log_2 d(2))} => \theta(n^3) $$
Time Complexity is then $\theta(8^r) $ which is derived from $n = 2^N$ where $n$ is the number of bits of its binary code.

Am I correct in assuming five recursive calls for the time complexity algorithm? Is the final time complexity correct with respect to bits? Is bounding by five function calls enough or will the upper bound be greater than the tight bound that I calculated?

Comment: Hem, I count $4$ recursive calls, and they are not all with argument $n/2$...

Comment: Is the empty loop intended ? Are the self-canceling calls intended ?

Comment: Yes the empty loop is the "driving function". I counted the 5 recursive calls from the fact that we're multiplying the recursive call by 2 plus the inner recursive call and the other two recursive calls. The self cancelling calls are intended, but don't they still factor into the time complexity?

Comment: The multiplication does not influence the number of calls, hence $4$. And what is $XYZ(n)$ returning ?

Comment: $XYZ(1) = 2$ is the base case for the function. If I am considering the nested function call as 1 recursion, is there a reason for changing the argument of the outer function to something other than $n/2$?

Comment: The question is: what is $XYZ(n)$ ? For instance, $XYZ(2)$ and $XYZ(4)$ ?

Comment: $XYZ(n) = 2*XYZ(XYZ(n/2)/2) + XYZ(n/2) - XYZ(n/2)$ for $n = 2^k$

Comment: Can you give an explicit formula ?

Comment: If I'm assuming correctly it should be $T(n) = 4 * T(n/2) + 2n^2$ with $2n^2$ being the amount of calulations done in each recursive call.

Comment: I am not asking about $T(n)$ but $XYZ(n)$. You need to know it to compute $T(n)$.

Comment: It should be $XYZ(n) = XYZ(n/4) + XYZ(n/2) - XYZ(n/2)$

Comment: This is not an explicit formula, and it is wrong.

Comment: What form would the explicit formula take?

Comment: $XYZ(n)= f(n)$.

Comment: Well if $XYZ(2) = 2$ And $XYZ(4)=4)$ then by reduction it is XYZ(n)= f(n/4)?

Comment: How do you justify $XYZ(2)=2$ ? And what is $f$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let us assume $n=2^k$ for convenience.

We first establish the value of $\text{XYZ}(n)$.

By the recursive definition,

```
XYZ(2) = 2XYZ(XYZ(1)/2)-XYZ(1)+XYZ(1) = 2XYZ(1) = 4,
XYZ(4) = 2XYZ(XYZ(2)/2)-XYZ(2)+XYZ(2) = 2XYZ(2) = 8,
XYZ(8) = 2XYZ(XYZ(4)/2)-XYZ(4)+XYZ(4) = 2XYZ(4) = 16,
...
```

and obviously $\text{XYZ}(n)=2n$.

Then for $n>1$, a call of $\text{XYZ}$ involves $3$ recursive calls with the argument $\frac n2$, and another with the argument $\frac{\text{XYZ}(\frac n2)}2$, which happens to also be $\frac n2$.

If we count the number of iterations of the empty loop,

$$T(n)=4T\left(\frac n2\right)+2n^2.$$

Try a solution of the form $n^2(a+b\log_2(n))$.

Comment: I see where you derived it from now, many thanks for taking the time to write it out. Recursion is not my strongest subject, but you've definitely helped me understand where the T(n) formula is derived from than most of my professors here do.

Comment: I must admit that this isn't the simplest of the exercises.

Comment: Sorry to bug you Yves, but I'm trying to figure our the complexity class of the basic, non-trivial [M] game and am not sure how to formulate a question that won't be ignored.  "Basic non-trivial" means a 9x9 Sudoku. Here are the rules: http://www.fundamentalcombinatronics.com/rules-of-m/ .  There is also a mobile app [mbrane](http://mbranegame.com/), which most find more useful than reading the rules.  Any guidance would be greatly apprciated.

Comment: @DukeZhou: problems with a fixed size have no asymptotic complexity. They are all $O(1)$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for that!  What about problems without fixed size, for instance the same Sudoku boards structure only m^n(m^n)?